# Reference request: Structure of $H^1({{\mathbf{Q}}_{q}},{{{{E}}_{{p}^{\infty}}}})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

I need reference on the structure of ${H}^{1}({{\mathbf{Q}}_{q}},{{E}_{{{p}^{\infty}}}})$, in particular when:

(1.) $q=p$

and/or

(2.) $E$ has multiplicative reduction at $q$.

Here, $E$ is an elliptic curve or, more generally, an Abelian variety.

Any suggestions on literature?

Comment: Virtually any book on Iwasawa theory of elliptic curves will consider these groups at some point. Coates--Sujatha "Galois cohomology of elliptic curves" would be a good place to start.